# Get sum of all integers in JSON file Python

Tags: python, json

I have a bot that allows users to collect virtual currency. I want the users to also be able to see the total amount of currency in circulation among other users.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
async def open_account(self, user):
  users = await self.get_bank_data()

  if str(user.id) in users:
    return False
  else:
    users[str(user.id)] = {}
    users[str(user.id)]["wallet"] = 0
    users[str(user.id)]["ducks"] = 0

  with open("bank.json", "w") as f:
    json.dump(users, f)

async def get_bank_data(self):
  with open("bank.json", "r") as f:
    users = json.load(f)
  return users

total = users["wallet"]
print(total)
```

I know that the whole top part works, but the last 2 lines don't. It seems as if it won't get the total for all instances of wallet.
This is my JSON file that stores all the bank's data looks like:

```
{"593918554055770115": {"wallet": 95170, "ducks": 0}, "735634891189780501": {"wallet": 4594, "ducks": 0}, "449356881362812938": {"wallet": 41564, "ducks": 0}, "439563730766790657": {"wallet": 0, "ducks": 0}, "479399392655441920": {"wallet": 6596, "ducks": 0}, "179653145067126784": {"wallet": 6594, "ducks": 0}, "397606114411282433": {"wallet": 0, "ducks": 0}, "792181275392868403": {"wallet": 23142, "ducks": 0}, "582072493716537345": {"wallet": 0, "ducks": 0}, "881231366820364369": {"wallet": 0, "ducks": 0}, "170862531504635905": {"wallet": 50, "ducks": 0}, "332990110830166026": {"wallet": 1222, "ducks": 0}}
```

I want to be able to get all instances of "wallet" and total it so I can display the total amount of money in circulation
The bot just simply doesn't work. I think the problem lies with this line of code: `total = users["wallet"]`

hopefully, somebody can help me with this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below

```
data = {"593918554055770115": {"wallet": 95170, "ducks": 0}, "735634891189780501": {"wallet": 4594, "ducks": 0}, "449356881362812938": {"wallet": 41564, "ducks": 0}, "439563730766790657": {"wallet": 0, "ducks": 0}, "479399392655441920": {"wallet": 6596, "ducks": 0}, "179653145067126784": {"wallet": 6594, "ducks": 0}, "397606114411282433": {"wallet": 0, "ducks": 0}, "792181275392868403": {"wallet": 23142, "ducks": 0}, "582072493716537345": {"wallet": 0, "ducks": 0}, "881231366820364369": {"wallet": 0, "ducks": 0}, "170862531504635905": {"wallet": 50, "ducks": 0}, "332990110830166026": {"wallet": 1222, "ducks": 0}}
wallet_sum = sum(v['wallet'] for v in data.values())
print(wallet_sum)
```

output

```
178932
```